# Typescript: Generic Removal of Type from string-type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a simple

```
type ExampleType = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
```

which is used in the following way:

```
from(from: ExampleType) {
    return {
        to: (to: ExampleType) => {
            // move something from/to
        },
    }
}
```

I am trying to have the "to-Function" only accept values that are not the value passed in the parameter "from".
I tried using Omit and Exclude but they both won't accept a dynamic value.

Can this be achieved in typescript?

I want to use it like

```
move(something).from('a').to('b'); // .to() should only accept 'b' and 'c'
```

and it would be really nice, would the IDE make the correct suggestions for that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this satisfies what you're looking for: Use `T extends ExampleType` then `Exclude<ExampleType, T>`

```
type ExampleType = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';

const from = <T extends ExampleType>(from: T) => {
    return {
        to: (to: Exclude<ExampleType, T>) => {
            // move something from/to
        },
    }
}

from('a').to('b'); // good
from('a').to('c'); // good
from('a').to('a'); // TypeError
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=32#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgQwLZgDYQCrmgXigcgXygB8CAjYs-AY3wG4AoRmgewDsBnYKAMwCdWSKHgA8GKBDjAI7ACadYiFOiyQAfAAoBQgFxQMAShHqoAb0ZQrUfhGABXfu3OXrb4K32aP++DVT2chCi8MhomNgANAbqxjimFm5J1gD0KVBIrABu0JxCdgAWAJbsAOZ8gkgpHq7JAL6RtVB1jC2MOkiahPiGAHQeXZSG9FBpUKWsrHLtlV1EfQO0PSNjE1MzQnM9-axbw6PpahAw-IL8QA)

Comment: Elegant way to handle it !

Comment: Sir, you are my hero of today! Have a great weekend and thank you very much!

Comment: No problem! This was a great question. I initially wasn't sure if it would be possible, so I learned something as well!

Comment: When getting an answer like that, I realize that I have so much to learn in Typescript :-)